# c# How To Access Elements of a List<Class>

Tags: c#, list

I want to access a certain field within a Class List so that I can do a calculation within a loop.

Here's my Class Firstly:

```
public class Hold
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public Double XPosition { get; set; }
    public Double YPosition { get; set; }
}
```

then my list `List<Hold>Data;`

I then use Linq to Store values from a Query.

What I ideally want to do is access the Time part of the List like so:

```
for(int i =0; i < Data.Count; i++)
{
    double average = Data.Time  // etc etc
}
```

Comment: I would like to know waht you want to do inside your for loop, perhaps there is a simpler way using Linq and completely remove the loop

Comment: from the naming of his variable, I'd assume he's trying to calculate the average of his Dates.
Please notice that you can't assign a DateTime to a double and that declaring the variable inside the loop won't make it visible outside. Also, the way you're assigning values, will overwrite the previous one at every iteration.

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano I *bet* this is not all of his code. Maybe he does some more with the "loop-local" variable? Do you know?

Comment: You're probably right, but he still can't assign a DateTime to a double, and the naming of the variable doesn't match with what the code shows.

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano Well, what is `etc etc`? Maybe it is `.TotalMillseconds`. And all of a sudden it is correct. I just think that it is unfair to downvote answers based on mistakes in the original question. You might as well downvote all the answers that quote string-concatenated SQL statements because it is open to SQL injections. The OP wants to know how to index the list/how to access members of individual items in the list and that's what we're showing. He's not asking for how to build an average over a `DateTime` (whatever that value would be, anyway).

Comment: I get your point Thorsten, but I think that at least the code we suggest as answers should not contain syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use indexer `Data[i]` with the list object. You have data type of DateTime and should not be assigned to double directly.

```
for(int i =0; i < Data.Count; i++)
{    
   //double average = Data[i].Time; 
   //Your code goes here.
}
```

You can use foreach loop

```
for(var data in Data)
{
    //data.Time         //You can use data.Time here
}
```

Comment: declaring the variable inside the for will always reassign its value at the next iteration. The Time property is a DateTime and can't be assigned to a double. The variable declared inside the for won't be visible outside the for loop

Answer (score 1):

Looking for a simple foreach?

```
foreach(Hold h in Data)
{
     DateTime t = h.Time;

     ... other properties or whatever method defined for the class Hold
}
```

A `List<T>` implements the [IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface, so it is natural to use foreach when you need to loop over all the elements of the List and extract its objects

The only possible problem with the foreach approach is if you need to remove elements from the list while iterating over them. But if you don't need this, then foreach is the most simple and natural way to access the elements contained in the list.

However it would be interesting to know what you want to do inside the loop.
Perhaps there are simpler ways using Linq and completely remove the loop.

For example, if you want to calculate the average seconds of your Time values stored in the list you could remove the loop using

```
 var k = data.Select(x => new TimeSpan(x.Time.Hour, x.Time.Minute, x.Time.Second))
             .Average(z => z.TotalSeconds);
```

Comment: declaring the variable inside the foreach will always reassign its value at the next iteration. The Time property is a DateTime and can't be assigned to a double. The variable declared inside the foreach won't be visible outside the foreach loop.

Comment: I was just fixing it, The problem is that we don't know what the OP really want to do within the loop. It seems that he wants to calculate some kind of average, but with the data provided is difficult to give an exact answer.

Comment: You're right, I was pointing to a few things, that are mostly resolved in the current revision of your snippet.

Comment: Seems like what I was trying to do and What I seem to be after thanks Steve, and Thank you everyone for the Fast Responses !

Answer (score 1):

The list does not have a "Time part". The objects held by the list have a `Time` member.

You could do this:

```
for(int i =0; i < Data.Count; i++)   
{
    double average = Data[i].Time etc etc
}
```

---

To make Saverio Terracciano happy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++)   
{
    // Access members of Hold, write something like
    ... = Data[i].<Member Name>
}
```

If you don't evaluate the `i` in any other place than just for indexing the list, you could also write

```
foreach (Hold h in Data)
{
    ... = h.<Member Name>;
}
```

Comment: declaring the variable inside the for will always reassign its value at the next iteration. The Time property is a DateTime and can't be assigned to a double. The variable declared inside the for won't be visible outside the for loop.

Comment: Before you downvote, please next time read the original post? I'm just quoting what the OP wrote. You could as well argue that `etc etc` is not valid C# syntax...

Comment: Yes, but if there is something wrong in the original post, I don't think this should imply a wrong answer. You can't directly cast a DateTime to a double.

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano Neither you and me know whether the `double average ...` line is his real code. I think it's a bit unfair to downvote answers based on zero knowledge and your own "best practice" understanding.

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano Hope that you are happier now.

Comment: I didn't want to be a jerk to you, considering that the OP seems to be new, I didn't want to side-track him from his main issue, when he compiled and the assignment of a DateTime to a double would make his compilation fail.

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano I know, but you'd have a lot of work if you wanted to get all the answers fixed where mistakes from the original question are quoted. Sometimes it's just ok to use mistakes from the original question in your answer as long as you answer the question. I wonder anyway what the average of a `DateTime` would be or indicate... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To create the average of a member of a list you need to take two steps:

You need to *transform* the list of class instances to a list of values you want to do your calculation on. You can do this using the `Select` extension method.

You need to calculate the average. You can do this using the `Average` extension method.

```
var data = new List<Hold>();

// fill list 

var transformed = data.Select(hold => hold.Time);

var average = transformed.Average();
```

You can do this in one simple step by using an overload of the Average extension method that includes a transform:

```
var average = data.Average(hold => hold.Time);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly (from your variable name) you want to calculate the average over your datetime values. You should do something like this:

```
double totalTicks=0D;
foreach(var x in Data){
   totalTicks+=x.Time.Ticks;
}
double averageTicks=totalTicks / Data.Count();
DateTime avgDateTime=new DateTime(averageTicks);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//get all values of Time Property from Data collection
List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();
Data.ForEach((h)=> { dateList.Add(h.Time); });
```