# How to iterate and access elements on a List<> in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having trouble figuring just exactly how to access and iterate through a List<> of a class and output the values within the class itself. Essentially what I'm trying to do is:
`Console.WriteLine(Football.team, Football.year, etc)`
for a long list of teams that I have imported form a `.csv` file.

Please go easy as I'm a newbie at C# programming.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    { // Bring in values from .csv file
        List<Football> values = File.ReadAllLines("/Users/wheelK/Documents/football.csv")
                                       .Skip(1)
                                       .Select(v => Football.FromCsv(v))
                                       .ToList();

    }

public class Football
    {
        public string team;
        public int year;
        public int wins;
        public int losses;
        public int ties;
    }
```

Comment: @selman lighten up. We're all here to learn!

Comment: @SelmanGenç Thanks for the help!

Comment: But, even easier than posting a question on Stack Overflow is doing a quickie internet search. I took your question, threw away most of the words and boiled it down to: "c# iterate list". Then i googled those words on Bing and came up with useful information. Google/Bing/etc are very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop:

```
foreach(var football in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(football.team);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758550/c-sharp-how-to-access-elements-of-a-listclass

Seemed to be the most directly relatable article that helped me the most. Forgive me for being such a scrub. I'll spend an hour and 5 minutes next time instead of just an hour.

Comment: Just glad you've got it now.